# HTML source newlike makes space between objects - how to get rid of this?

Tags: html, css

I have code like this:

```
<button>B1</button>
<button>B2</button>
<button>B3</button>
```

After some styling and removing all paddings and margins it produces output like this:

[image]

I know, that browser renders spaces where I have newlines in HTML code.

My question is:

**Do I have to make my code less readable like this to get rid of these spaces?**

```
<button>B1</button><button>B2</button><button>B3</button>
```

I'm using HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: Please add your css as well for better understanding or jfiddle

Comment: When you use float:left doesn't work? button{float: left;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `buttons` inside a `div` and give that `div` a `font-size` of `0` to remove the space between the buttons.

```css
.btn-group {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button>B1</button>
  <button>B2</button>
  <button>B3</button>
</div>
```